# In order to save the size of exported SVG file, I want to reuse a symbol but how could I do that with Sketch?

Tags: svg, sketchapp

I am using Sketch 70.2 (so far the latest version).

I have a symbol and two instances on the stage:

[image]

However, when I exported this, the exported SVG didn't take advantage of reusing that symbol. It would boost the SVG file size especially when the symbol is very complicated.

Is there any way/settings to tell Sketch to do so?

[image]

Comment: Your bigger issue is the bytes precision take. You output to 984px width, but with 7 digits precision (``50.8418134``) you are effectivly **drawing 10,000,000 pixels into one pixel**. Use https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ you probably only want 1 digit precision, in which case you can multiply everyting **including the viewBox** by 10 to have 0 precision

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).